# ASP.NET MVC - Preserve POST data after Authorize attribute login redirect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I have a blog post page with comments.
Any user (logged in or not) can see a form at the bottom of the page to post a comment.
When user enters the comment and she is not authorized - the user is redirected to a login/signup page.
After logged in, the user is redirected back to the action, but the POST data, containing the comment body, is lost.

I use the ASP.NET MVC Authorize attribute to require authorization on some actions:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), Authorize]
public ActionResult Create(int blogPostID, string commentBody) {
    var comment = new Comment {
       Body = commentBody,
       BlogPostID = blogPostID,
       UserName = User.Identity.Name
    }
    // persist the comment and redirect to a blog post page with recently added comment
}
```

How do you solve this problem?

Making user loggin before displaying the comment form is a bad idea here I think.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably just save off the siteId and comment into the Session. Then create another overload for Create that doesn't take any parameters. It checks to see if these variables exist in the session - if so, pass it off to your original Create method.

To do that, you'd have to remove the Authorize attribute and just do the security check yourself. Something like this:

```
var user = HttpContext.User;

if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{ 
   Session["Comment"] = comment;
   Session["SiteId"] = siteId;
   return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account", 
                           new { returnUrl = "/ControllerName/Create"} );
}
```

Then your overloaded Create:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var comment = (Session["Comment"] ?? "").ToString();
    int siteId = 0;
    if (Session["siteId"] != null)
        siteId = (int)Session["siteId"];

    return Create(siteId, comment);
}
```

Of course, this isn't really all that generic and doesn't handle more complex scenarios, but it's an idea. (hopefully the above code works, I haven't had a chance to test it). It seems like you could maybe do something like this via an action filter but I don't have any sample code for that.

Comment: Thanks, looks usable. I changed the action parameters from "siteId, comment" to "int blogPostID, string commentBody" in my initial question, but the idea is clear.

Comment: I decided to go with this solution. It works fine as for now. There could be problems in a web-farm if session is not populated across all servers. In that case I would store a comment in a database without the UserId and put the CommentId to the visitor's cookie, and after authorization, update the Comment record with the authorized UserId.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hidden field on your authorization form. Put your user's comment to that field (your initial POST data). After that you still can not use the data on your comment form if authorization form simply redirects to your comments form. So make your authorization form post to comments form, data in hidden field will be posted also, so you can use it.

Comment: Authorization includes OAuth/OpenID options that causes redirect to Facebook/Twitter. External OAuth authorize page doesn't support the "hidden input contract" and the data is still lost.