# ASP.NET Core - Preserve POST data after Authorize attribute login redirect

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

This is essentially the same question as this one:
[ASP.NET MVC - Preserve POST data after Authorize attribute login redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096700/asp-net-mvc-preserve-post-data-after-authorize-attribute-login-redirect) except it isn't asked 7 years ago, and it's about ASP.NET Core, which is pretty different. I am using the `[Authorize]` attribute to do my most basic access authentication, really just to check to see if there is a user logged in at all. If not, then it kicks them back to the login page. Here's the services setup for that.

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "loginId";
    });
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/Account/Logout");
```

Here is my Logout action.

```cs
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(string returnUrl = "/cgi-s/admin.cgi")
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
    if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("loginId", out string loginId))
    {
        User auth = _context.Users.Where(a => a.LoginId.Equals(loginId)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (auth != null)
        {
            auth.LoginId = string.Empty;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
    return Redirect("/Account/Login?returnUrl="+returnUrl);
}
```

Right now I am just using the default behavior with a return url string to get back to the attempted page after a successful login. Is there a way to set this up so that POST data is also preserved?

I've tried a couple different things, like a custom middleware that stores post data which then gets retrieved on login, but I haven't come up with anything that I haven't found security holes in afterward.

Is there an easy way to do this that I'm just missing?

Thanks.

PS. Please ignore the weirdness going on in the Logout action. We are a two man team working on a 20 year old Perl CGI site, slowly transitioning over to .NET while trying to also keep up with new features and bug fixes, so everything is weird while we run Perl CGI alongside some .NET code on IIS with Postgres. Hopefully we will eventually get everything transitioned over.

Comment: It is unreasonable for your needs. The methods provided in the link are not feasible for saving submission data for different models, you cannot ensure that the correct model data is obtained.

Comment: @XueliChen Agreed. I'm not sure what to do. For now, we have sidestepped the problem by trying to make everything that isn't multipart or insecure GET requests instead of POST requests, but that's not really a solution. This really seems like a failing of .NET Core that a solution for this isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried httpContext.Request.EnableBuffering?

See this question here and be sure to look at the comments: [Read the body of a request as string inside middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58466019/read-the-body-of-a-request-as-string-inside-middleware)

```
 httpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
 using(StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpContext.Request.Body, 
 ...,leaveOpen: true))
{

  //Do something here:


   httpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;
 }
```