# Read the body of a request as string inside middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

How can I read the body value as string from `HttpContext.Request` in ASP.NET Core 3.0 middleware?

```
private static void MyMiddleware(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.Run(async ctx =>
    {
        var body = ctx.Request.??????
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(body);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways to custom middleware like below:

1.The first way is that you could write middleware in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
       //...
        app.Run(async ctx =>
        {
            string body;
            using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(ctx.Request.Body, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                body = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
            await ctx.Response.WriteAsync(body);
        });    
       //... 
    }
```

2.The second way is that you could custom middleware class like below:

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        string body;
        using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(httpContext.Request.Body, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            body = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
        await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(body);
    }
}
```

Then you need to register in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        //...
        app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
        //...
    }
```

3.Result:
[image]

Reference: [Write custom ASP.NET Core middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: This works but doing so consumes the stream; in practice, you'll probably want to make it available to the rest of the pipeline. And this turns out to be a huge pain, since [the relevant functionality is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58737391/5085211) in ASP.NET Core 3.0. (Who'd have thought to test that a web framework could read web request bodies ...)