# How can I read http request body in netcore 3 more than once?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a netcore 3 API application that logs the incoming request and then passes it on to the controller action.

My code looks like this:

```
public RequestLoggingHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}


protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RequestLoggingRequirement requirement)
{
    try
    {
        var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        var request = httpContext.Request;

        _repository = (ICleanupOrderRepository)httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ICleanupOrderRepository));
        _cache = (IMemoryCache)httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IMemoryCache));

        httpContext.Items["requestId"] = SaveRequest(request);

        context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }
}

private int SaveRequest(HttpRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        // Allows using several time the stream in ASP.Net Core
        var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];
       request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        var requestContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        var requestId = _repository.SaveRawHandlerRequest($"{request.Scheme} {request.Host}{request.Path} {request.QueryString} {requestContent}");

        return requestId;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }
}
```

However when this request is passed on to the Controller the request body is null.

Previously in Core2.x you could do

```
request.EnableRewind();
```

My understanding is this is now replaced with

```
httpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
```

However, even with

```
httpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
```

the request body is still null once the request body is read.

How can I get around this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a known [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14396) on github.

A temp workaround is to pull out the body right after the call to EnableBuffering and then rewinding the stream to 0 and not disposing it:

```
public class RequestLoggingHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RequestLoggingRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public RequestLoggingHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RequestLoggingRequirement requirement)
    {
        try
        {
            var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            var request = httpContext.Request;
            request.EnableBuffering();

            httpContext.Items["requestId"] = SaveRequest(request);
            context.Succeed(requirement);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    private int SaveRequest(HttpRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            // Allows using several time the stream in ASP.Net Core
            var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];
            request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            var requestContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            var requestId = _repository.SaveRawHandlerRequest($"{request.Scheme} {request.Host}{request.Path} {request.QueryString} {requestContent}");

            request.Body.Position = 0;//rewinding the stream to 0
            return requestId;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is works only for small requests. In my case, the request crashes when it reaches 32kb. It crashes because of the inability to read the call parameters from Request.Body in the main method.